# FileSystemWatcher state Not started

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to register an event for when a file is created or changed in a directory. When I try to register the event, the state remains "Not Started" and the event does not work.

```cs
function checkFilestatus {
    Param($k)
    try {
        [IO.File]::OpenRead($k).Close()
        Copy-Item -Path "$k\" -Destination "\\ServerName\D$\Temp\MyFolder" -Recurse -Force
    } catch {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
        Copy-Item -Path "$k\" -Destination "\\ServerName\D$\Temp\MyFolder" -Recurse -Force
    }
}
$filewatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$filewatcher.Path = "D:\MyFolder\Folder2"
$filewatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$filewatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Created" -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { checkFilestatus($($EventArgs.FullPath)) }
Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Changed" -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action { checkFilestatus($($EventArgs.FullPath)) }
```

Following is the output when I run the script:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------
40     FileCreated                     NotStarted    False
41     FileChanged                     NotStarted    False
```