# PowerShell FileSystemWatcher state NotStarted

Tags: powershell

I have the exact same problem like this question [FileSystemWatcher state Not started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681178/filesystemwatcher-state-not-started) unfortunately, no one seemed to know the answer to this, that's why I'm trying my luck with basically the same question :).

This is my code:

```
# Source Pfad festlegen
$Sourcepath = "C:\install" 

# Watcher objekt erstellen
$watcher = [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher]::new()
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.Path = $Sourcepath
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Aktionen festlegen
$action = {
    $event | fl *
    $event.sourceeventargs | fl *
}

$erstellt = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -Action $action -SourceIdentifier File
```

But the Event is never started `State : NotStarted` as you can see here:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $erstellt | fl *


State         : NotStarted
Module        : __DynamicModule_dcdf5dd5-0032-42ad-902f-06e15f5cf3fa
StatusMessage :
HasMoreData   : False
Location      :
Command       :
                    $event | fl *
                    $event.sourceeventargs | fl *

JobStateInfo  : NotStarted
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : 87072caa-32dc-45c9-b10b-7aa4f455a3aa
Id            : 1
Name          : File
ChildJobs     : {}
PSBeginTime   :
PSEndTime     :
PSJobTypeName :
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
Information   : {}
```

I tried this in `PowerShell.exe`, `PowerShell.exe` as Admin, and `PowerShell_ISE` and my eventjob never got started. why? How can I start it?

**EDIT:** As the answer suggests, the starting is not a problem. I thought it was a Problem, because I've never received any output. looks like output is discarded, except it's done via `Write-Host`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't see the result of your action because the **output from a triggered event action is simply discarded**. I just change the action and it works for me. Don't forget to create a file the directory to have the event fired.

```
# Source Pfad festlegen
$Sourcepath = "C:\install" 

# Watcher objekt erstellen
$watcher = [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher]::new()
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.Path = $Sourcepath
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Aktionen festlegen
$action = {
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -ForegroundColor red 
}

$erstellt = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -Action $action -SourceIdentifier "File"
```

I've got :

```
Get-EventSubscriber 


SubscriptionId   : 4
SourceObject     : System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
EventName        : Created
SourceIdentifier : File
Action           : System.Management.Automation.PSEventJob
HandlerDelegate  : 
SupportEvent     : False
ForwardEvent     : False
```

and :

```
$erstellt |fl *


State         : Running
Module        : __DynamicModule_91fdc1aa-45b4-4c37-8c35-167cc41f5fa0
StatusMessage : 
HasMoreData   : True
Location      : 
Command       : 
                $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
                $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
                Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore red 

JobStateInfo  : Running
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : 15acf6ef-c89d-4ebb-8be3-2000ea5cfa43
Id            : 3
Name          : File
ChildJobs     : {}
PSBeginTime   : 13/02/2018 15:52:39
PSEndTime     : 
PSJobTypeName : 
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
Information   : {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like the State get's only triggered to "Running" when the first file gets created / changed / deleted. It also looks like I can only see an output if I use `Write-Host`. `$event | fl *`does not give me a return but `Write-Host ($event | fl *)` does. weird. do you have an idea why i can't see output without `Write-host` ?

Comment: I usualy consider that the action scriptblock is not suppose to be run in the foreground. So I never use Write-host. The output from a triggered event action is simply discarded.